# How do I include webjob files while debugging locally but exclude when publishing a web package?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-deployment, target, azure-webjobs

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and have a solution with several web projects and webjob projects.

There are some files that I want to *include* when running locally in the development environment that I want to *exclude* from being deployed as part of a web publishing package.

I'm attempting to use the process described here http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx and elsewhere, which is:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ExcludeFromPackageFiles Include="connectionstrings.config">
      <FromTarget>Project</FromTarget>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </ExcludeFromPackageFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This works perfectly for my web projects - meaning that when building the connectionstrings.config file is copied to my `bin\` directory and not included as part of the web deployment package - whereas when implemented in my webjob projects the file is copied to my `bin\` directory but also included in the deployment package.

In the msbuild output I see:

> Copying file from "C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\myapp\myapp\webjob1\connectionstrings.config" to "bin\ProdBuildCfg\connectionstrings.config".

which is what I want because it allows me to run/debug locally, and also:

> Copying C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\myapp\myapp\webjob1\bin\ProdBuildCfg\connectionstrings.config to obj\ProdBuildCfg\Package\PackageTmp\app_data\jobs\continuous\webjob1\connectionstrings.config.

which demonstrates the problem - connectionstrings.config is still being copied to the package directory for subsequent publishing/deployment.

The process described in the above article and others applies to web projects, and they indicate you should place the `<ItemGroup>` under the

`<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />`

line of the project file.  Webjob projects don't include that line but rather have something resembling:

`<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.13\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.13\tools\webjobs.targets')" />`

I suspect the problem relates to targets - either my project file doesn't include the proper `<Import Project="...*.targets')" />` line or I'm not at the right spot in the file.

Next I tried the method mentioned here [How do I include webjob files while debugging locally but exclude when publishing a web package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735670/how-do-i-include-webjob-files-while-debugging-locally-but-exclude-when-publishin):

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">  
 <ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>connectionstrings.config</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have the connectionstrings.config Build Action set to `None` and `Copy to output directory` set to `Always` (my understanding is that action that results from the `Copy to output directory` setting is distinctly different from the actions associated with packaging/deployment).  Same result.  (I've ensured I'm in the right `<PropertyGroup>` for my build configuration.

Note: I'm deploying either by right-clicking the project in VS and selecting "Publish as Azure webjob" or using an msbuild command to publish like `msbuild myproj.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile="Prod" /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0 /p:Password=`

Answer (score 1):

> How do I include webjob files while debugging locally but exclude when publishing a web package?

To my knowledge, if you do not want to publish any file, you just need to set the file property to "**copy to output directory** as **DO NOT COPY**". This way when you will package the application that particular file will not be part of package and will never be on Azure.

**Update:**

> Unfortunately that setting prevents the file from being copied to the
>   output directory which means I can’t run or debug locally.

When you debugging the project, you can set the "`copy to output directory`" as "`Copy always`". When you want to deploy the project, you can manually clean the build and change the value to `DO NOT COPY`.

If you do not want to do all those manually, I would like provide you a workaround, hope this can help you.

To accomplish this, unload your project. Then at the very end of the project , just before the end-tag, place below scripts:

```
  <Target Name="ExcludeFileFromPackage" BeforeTargets="PipelineCopyAllFilesToOneFolderForMsdeploy">
    <Message Text="Delete the connectionstrings.config from Obj folder to exculde this file in the package directory" />

    <Delete Files="$(ProjectDir)obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\connectionstrings.config" />
  </Target>
```

With this target, VS/MSBuild will delete the `connectionstrings.config` from the obj folder before publish the project as package.

Comment: Unfortunately that setting prevents the file from being copied to the output directory which means I can’t run or debug locally. There are some files that I want to include when running locally in the development environment that I want to exclude from being deployed as part of a web publishing package.

Comment: @Howiecamp, thanks for your reply. It seems the property of `ExcludeFromPackageFiles` does not work for webjob project. To resolve this issue, I provided a workaround to you, you can check the updated answer for detailed info. Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try the `<Target Name=...>` approach you're suggesting.  Should it work the same whether I publish via an `msbuild.exe` command line (see my question for example) or publish it interactively by right-clicking in VS and choosing "Publish as Azure webjob"?

Comment: @Howiecamp, it should be work whether you publish via msbuild command line and in VS.